# android webview not scrolling horizontally

Tags: android, css, webview

I am loading some pdf document inside `webview` in `android`, but its not scrolling horizontally, but scrolls vertically. When I inspected the `url` in chrome inspect, I found "overflow" `css` is coming as "hidden", and when I changed it to scroll, it started working. How can I make that change in my code.

```
   html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the one I found while doing chrome inspect.How can I change it to overflow: scroll programmatically for `webview.loadurl()`

Comment: you can call Javascript, which will change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.document.getElementsByTagName('body') 
 [0].overflow='hidden';");
```

Js code may be wrong, but the idea is right.